# ocamlbuild and OUnit

Tags: makefile, ocaml, ocamlbuild, ounit

I have a project structured like this:

```
Makefile
src/
  main.ml
tests/
  tests.ml
```

and the `Makefile` is something like this:

```
tests:
    ocamlbuild -Is src,tests tests.byte -build-dir $(BUILDDIR) $(TESTFLAGS) -lflags -I,/usr/lib/ocaml/oUnit -cflags -I,/usr/lib/ocaml/oUnit -libs oUnit
```

Running `make tests` (after building `main.byte`) returns this error:

```
ocamlbuild -Is src,tests tests.byte -build-dir build -lflags -I,/usr/lib/ocaml/oUnit -cflags -I,/usr/lib/ocaml/oUnit -libs oUnit 
+ /usr/bin/ocamlc -c -I /usr/lib/ocaml/oUnit -I tests -I src -o tests/tests.cmo tests/tests.ml
File "tests/tests.ml", line 3, characters 46-50:
Error: Unbound value main
Command exited with code 2.
Compilation unsuccessful after building 2 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:00.
make: *** [tests] Error 10
```

showing that `ocamlbuild` cannot link to `main.byte`. What should the `tests` rule of the `Makefile` look like?

Answer (score 3):

Since OCaml programs don't have a default main function (OCaml just runs the top-level code in each module at start-up) you'll probably want to have a separate file for starting the code. e.g.

```
main.ml
myprog.ml
tests.ml
```

Where:

- `main.ml` defines a main function `let main args = ...`
- `myprog.ml` just calls it: `let () = Main.main Sys.argv`
- `tests.ml` calls it in the same way from each test-case

Then build `myprog.byte` and `tests.byte` as your two targets to ocamlbuild. Run `myprog.byte` to run the program and `tests.byte` to run the tests.

Answer (score 0):

`unbound value main` does not sound like an error related to `main.byte`, but a genuine mistake in the OCaml code of `tests.ml`. Could you provide (possibly simplified) sources to experiment?

(Thomas' advice on program structure of course still stands, independently.)